# How to use an external Auth token in multiple AWS lambdas

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm using Node.Js to create lambdas. My first lambda is an Authorizer connect to an external server and gets an auth token. My second, third and fourth lambdas use that auth token to make http post calls for verification in the header of the call and execute the functions.
If I save the token from the auth lambda into an environment variable, can I reuse it in other lambdas. Or save it to a Dynomodb table and use from it. I like to know which one is a better option and if any other suggestions how to achieve it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your auth token lambda behind api gateway and enable [api gateway caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html) with TTL as per your token expiration time.

Another option is to set the token in memory and invoke your auth lambda if token is not set in memory. So in every first invocation with cold start your auth token lambda will be invoked and you can save the token in some global level variable.

Make sure you are using one instance of `AuthTokenService` in your code.

```
class AuthTokenService {
    constructor() {
        this.token = '';
    }

    async getToken() {
        if (!this.token) {
            this.token = <Token from some api/lambda>
        }
        return this.token;
    }
}

module.exports = AuthTokenService;
```

Comment: Hey Pankaj, I like to know more your latter suggestion. Can you give me a sample code how to do it with node.js. i.e: to set a token in memory and reuse it as a global variable